# Error showing ReferenceError: inject is not defined. trying to get give hit the server using $http

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, karma-jasmine, jasmine-node

Error thrown:

> ReferenceError: inject is not defined.

I'm trying to hit the server using angular $http method. I was able to do the same by using npm require library. When I'm trying to do the same with $http I'm facing an issue.

I got angular.mocks.js also installed through npm. can anyone please rectify it. thank you.

```
    describe("POST /", function() {
    var $http;
    beforeEach (inject(function ($injector) {
    $http = $injector.post("$http");
    });

    it('should demonstrate using when (201 status)', function () {

         $http.post('http://localhost:9080/', data, config)
         .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
              $scope.valid = true;
              $scope.response = data;
            })
            .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
              $scope.valid = false;
          });

           expect($scope.valid).toBe(true);

    });


});
```

Comment: Can you post your karma config file?

Comment: I am not using Karma. I am using Jasmine node for all the dependencies. @MitchLillie